# regex find string, go back to "a word" and give me the next 6 characters

Tags: regex

Still being a newbie in regex, I would need this to be working with powershell.
+ It should give back all occurances ...

This is an example of the string (one big line) :

{"type":"HM","adr":"*30CC170*","state":"01:**FE**"},{"type":"HM","adr":"*37519701*","state":"00:FF"},{"type":"HM","adr":"*3AD95D01*","state":"FF:**FE**"},

Now, search for **FE** and give me back the values 30CC1701 & 3AD95D01 (always 8 characters, and immediatly after adr":")

Anyone that can assist ?  Would be greatfull :o)

Comment: Isn't this some `JSON` output? Why not use a parser?

Comment: Second that. Unless in a one-off script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"adr":"([^"]{8})"[^}]+?FE` would be a way to do it, where group 1 captures the 8-character value (or between 6 and 8 - `{6,8}`).

`(?<="adr":")[^"]{8}(?="[^}]+FE)` would capture same as a whole match with non-capturing look-ahead/behind.

Returning all matches is a function of a particular API, rather than regex. It would be, I believe, the `-AllMatches` option in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you a good regex to start playing with. You should use it with the global flag to extract all occurences

```
\"adr\":\"([^"]+)\",\"state\":\"[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:FE\"
```

Regex explained below

```
\"adr\":             - Match "adr":
\"([^"]+)\"          - Capture a quoted string [^"]+ matches any non quoted character
,\"state\":          - Matches ,"state":
\"[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}\"   - Match a string in format "xx:FE" where x represent any a hex number 0-9 or A-F.
```